# Banach space induced by linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E, F$ be Banach spaces and $T: E \to F$ is a bounded injective map.

If we define on $E$ a norm $\|u\|_{\widetilde{E}}:= \| Tu \|_F, u \in E,$ then one easily see that $(E, \|\cdot\|_{\widetilde{E}})$ is a normed space.

In general, this space is not a Banach space. I would like to know if there are any conditions on $E,F$ or $T$, which makes $(E, \|\cdot\|_{\widetilde{E}})$ a Banach space.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the map $T \colon \left( E, \| \cdot \|_{\tilde{E}} \right) \rightarrow \left( F, \| \cdot \|_{F} \right)$ is an isometry which allows you to identify $\left( E, \| \cdot \|_{\tilde{E}} \right)$ with the image of $T$ (and the restriction of the norm $\| \cdot \|_{F}$ to the image). Hence, $\left( E, \| \cdot \|_{\tilde{E}} \right)$, or equivalently $\left( \operatorname{im}(T), \| \cdot \|_{F} \, |_{\operatorname{im}(T)} \right)$ is Banach if and only if the image of $T$ is a closed subspace of $F$.